# Appending a JSON file

Tags: javascript

I'm working in JAVASCRIPT and I am trying to append a JSON file. The top of the file looks like this ...

```
doUpdate(
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
.
.
.
);
```

I want to the top of the file to look like this and then to add the appropriate } at the end

```
doUpdate(
{
"data": {
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
.
.
.
.
}
);
```

I know this is kind of weird but I have a theory and I am working on an issue.

Comment: That isn't JSON.

Comment: This isn't appending, either.

Comment: And JavaScript doesn't have any native file handling capability anyway, it depends on the host environment to provide that sort of thing … and you didn't specify that. Windows Scripting Host? NodeJS? Something else?

Comment: @Quentin This is JSONP.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I think you mean [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: yeah yeah, I just had one of those moments

Comment: Curiously, there *is* a [PJSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pjson)

Comment: How is Question related to JavaScript?

Comment: @guest271314 the OP says he's working in javascript in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: @Clark See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You would need to take several steps to modify the object inside the function call. The bare-basic, dumbest, error-prone way is:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('myfile.js', 'utf8', function (str) {
  str = str.replace(/^doUpdate\(|\)$/g, ''); // modify this for newlines and semicolon
  obj = JSON.parse(str);
  obj['newContent'] = 'foo';
  obj['moreContent'] = 'bar';
  str = 'doUpdate(' + JSON.stringify(obj) + ')'; // or stringify(obj, null, 2) for pretty-print
  console.log(str);
  // or fs.writeFile('myfile.js', str);
});
```

A more robust way would be parsing and building an AST using Esprima, then grabbing the object, and rebuilding the output js.